# always getting this error (the following arguments are required: -i/--image)

Tags: image, python-3.5

```
from __future__ import print_function
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage.morphology import watershed
from scipy import ndimage
import argparse
import cv2
```

construct the argument parse and parse the arguments and alaways have the same error

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
help="path to input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

image = cv2.imread(args["C:/Users/Wael/Desktop/coins.jpg"])
shifted = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(image, 21, 51)
cv2.imshow("Input", image)
```

Comment: What is "the same error"? Can you share the exact error message?

Comment: removed some markup

Comment: This error : the following arguments are required: -i/--image